# Creating a simple CRUD wth VB 2010 and SQL Server 2008

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I need your help in connecting VB.NET 2010 to SQL Server 2008. I also want to know how to make a very simple CRUD application in VB.NET 2010 and display its records in a `DataGrid` or `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any quicker way to start than with ASP.NET Dynamic Data.  Take a look at this [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488469%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  You can have a database oriented crud screen in a few lines of code.

Comment: thanks Art but hmp, I'm not a web programmer. I moved to vb2010 to create desktop applications by using visual basic 2010, Honestly, i realy find hard and in don't know how to start.

Comment: Take a look at the MSDN samples for VB.NET. They cover a range of topics, one of which is data access. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ekc8at3(v=vs.100).aspx